# apply in R returns weird results

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I am trying to divide each row of my matrix by the sum of that same row:

```
a <- matrix(1:25,nrow=5,ncol=5)
a <- apply(a,1,function(x) x/sum(x))
```

this gives the intended result but it is structured in columns as opposed to rows:

```
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,] 0.01818182 0.03333333 0.04615385 0.05714286 0.06666667
[2,] 0.10909091 0.11666667 0.12307692 0.12857143 0.13333333
[3,] 0.20000000 0.20000000 0.20000000 0.20000000 0.20000000
[4,] 0.29090909 0.28333333 0.27692308 0.27142857 0.26666667
[5,] 0.38181818 0.36666667 0.35384615 0.34285714 0.33333333
```

Comment: didn't know that, i've just looked up ?matrix, do you think if I put byrow=TRUE, it would fix the problem ?

Comment: There is nothing called `col`. Please change that to `ncol` and for your desired result add `byrow =TRUE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the matrix is structured by columns, dividing the matrix by the row sums gives the correct result:

```
> a / rowSums(a)
           [,1]      [,2] [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 0.01818182 0.1090909  0.2 0.2909091 0.3818182
[2,] 0.03333333 0.1166667  0.2 0.2833333 0.3666667
[3,] 0.04615385 0.1230769  0.2 0.2769231 0.3538462
[4,] 0.05714286 0.1285714  0.2 0.2714286 0.3428571
[5,] 0.06666667 0.1333333  0.2 0.2666667 0.3333333
```

This works because the vector returned by `rowSums` is recycled.

For the `apply` to work, you would simply need to transpose the result, as the return value of `apply` is built up by column, not row.

Comment: so "a / rowSums(a)" divides rows of "a" by their respective sums is that the default way? what if you wanted to divide columns of "a" by rowSums ?

Comment: Say you wanted to divide each column by its sum, then you could use `apply` as you have done, or perhaps `a / rep(colSums(a), each=nrow(a))`.  Same for dividing each column by the row sum (for a square matrix).

Answer (score 0):

That's the way `apply` is supposed to work.  By default, matrices are filled by column in R.  Note the documentation for ?apply:

> If each call to FUN returns a vector of length n, then apply returns an array of dimension c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN]) if n > 1.